# Is IGraphicTracker leaking memory?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, .net, visual-studio

It seems that when geometries are removed from an IGraphicTracker instance, the geometries remain in memory until IAoInitialize.Shutdown() is called. I have tried removing the geometries by calling the IGraphicTracker.RemoveAll() method and by storing the IDs returned by IGraphicTracker.Add() method and calling the IGraphicTracker.Remove() method for each ID.

Is there something that I'm missing in the example provided below?

I'm currently using ArcGIS 10.1 and Visual Studio 10 targeting .NET Framework 3.5.

An example can be found here: http://forums.arcgis.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=20140&d=1356115382

This problem was originally noted on the ESRI Dev Forum: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/72516-Memory-Leak-with-Graphic-Tracker

Comment: Once try with framework 4.0